# Building platform-as-a-service

Tags: docker, cloud, paas

I have been assigned a problem statement which goes as follows:

I am building platform-as-a-service from scratch, which has pipelined execution. Here pipelined execution means that output of a service can be input into another service. The platform can offer number of services, which can be pipelined together. Output of a service can be input to multiple services.

I am new to this field so how to go about this task is not very intuitive to me.

After researching a bit, I found out that I can use Docker to deploy services in containers. So I installed Docker on Ubuntu and installed few images and run them as service (for example, MongoDB). What I am thinking of is that I need to run the services in containers, and define a way of taking input and output to these services. But how exactly do I do this using Docker containers. As an example, I want to send a query as an input to MongoDB (running as a service) and want an output, which I want to feed into another service.

1. Am I thinking in the right direction? If not in what direction should I be thinking of going about implementing this task?
2. Is there a standard way of exchanging data between services? (For example output of on service as input to another)
3. Is there something that Docker offers that I can leverage?

**NOTE: I cannot use any high level API which does this for me. I need to implement it myself.**

Comment: it sounds like you want to have an orchestrator to deploy servicers on demand. Maybe you would be more interested to implement a kubernetes or docker swarm solution.

Comment: @Stefano In my NOTE in the question, I was trying to refer to high level systems like the ones you have mentioned, which I cannot use. I want to implement them from scratch. That is I believe, the crux of the task.

Comment: Building everything from scratch is going to be a long and complex journey. We are building DevOps PaaS more than 7 years already and we are using some "ready to go" components as well. But of course amount of efforts depends on the set of features and level of product quality you want to achieve.